# Getting columns (instead of rows) using Reap/Sow

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

In my program, I'm computing a vector inside a `Do` loop. The example below is an overly-simplified version, but the structure is the same (the original code can't be reduced to a `Table`). Using Reap/Sow, I get the following result:

`In[1]:= v1 = Reap[Do[Sow[{{i, i}, {i^2, i^2}} // Transpose];, {i, 3}]][[2, 1]]`

`Out[1]= {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 4}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 9}, {3, 9}}}`

The final list I'm looking for is the transpose of this matrix:

`In[2]:= v1 = Transpose@v1`

`Out[2]= {{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}}`

The real vectors I'm working with are very large and Transposing the matrix after computing it takes a lot of time and memory (the dimensions of the vectors are around `{201, 2, 500 000}`). It often takes more time than computing the vector in the first place.

Is there a way to use Reap/Sow to arrange the vectors on columns instead of rows, in order to get the desired result without having to transpose at the end?

Comment: Read in the help under "Sow" about tagging. With this you can then write: v1 = Reap[Do[Sow[{i, i^2}, 1]; Sow[{i, i^2}, 2];, {i, 3}]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Sow` and `Reap` different tags like this:

```
v1 = Reap[
   Do[
    MapIndexed[
      Sow[#1, First @ #2] &,
      {{i, i}, {i^2, i^3}} // Transpose
    ];,
    {i, 3}
  ],
  Range[2]
][[2, All, 1]]
```

> {{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 8}, {3, 27}}}

Of course, you do need to know the number of tags to collect (2, in this case).